# Changing background color of Hamburger menu in react

Tags: reactjs, hamburger-menu

I am using the react-burger-menu and can't change the menu item background color from the default red/pink.  This is the react code I am using:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'
import './burger.css';
import icon from './menu.png';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class BurgerMenu extends Component {

    showSettings (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <Menu customBurgerIcon={ <img src={icon} /> }>
            <Link className="menu-item">Contact</Link>
            <Link className="menu-item">About</Link>
            <Link className="menu-item">Trending</Link>
            <Link className="menu-item">Settings</Link>
          </Menu>
        );
      }

}

export default BurgerMenu;
```

And here is the css I am using

```
.bm-burger-button {
    position: fixed;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 78px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: white;
  }

 .menu-item {
     padding: 5px;
     color: white;
 }

 .menu-item:hover {
     background-color: #808090;
 }
```

I also see a blue outline box around the first item, and whichever item I click.  Is there any way to get rid of that?

Here is the picture:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please share working example on https://stackblitz.com. Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z36ayd on here the background is transparent for some reason, but in my application it's like reddish-orange.

Comment: In above link the **Background color** is not transparent. Is like reddish-orange as you mention.

Comment: Sorry, not that one.  It's when you click the button and the menu comes out.  On my program the background is pink and I can't seem to figure out how to change it.

Comment: Please add screenshots in your question's description.

Comment: Just added the picture.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remove the background color for the menu item when hovering you can make it transparent like this :

```
.menu-item:hover {
     background-color: transparent;
 }
```

And for removing the blue border on links you can use `outline: none;` in your menu-item class like this :

```
 .menu-item {
     padding: 5px;
     color: white;
     outline: none;
 }
```

For the sidebar background color you can change it like this :

```
.bm-menu {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vdexmi)

Comment: Thanks! That removed that blue outline, however I still have that pink background.

Comment: can you try adding the styles for this class `bg-menu`, i'll add the content in the answer

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do anything.  Still getting that pink background on the pullout menu.  I added a screenshot in my question to show what the problem is.

Comment: do you have any other css files in your app ? which may apply that color ?

Comment: Hmm good question.  I'm honestly not super familiar with the react-burger-menu package, but there must be some default css in there.  I'll poke around in there and see what I can find.  Thanks

Comment: can you try inspecting the dom element in your browser and see where the color is coming from ?

Comment: Well that was the trick! Saw that the class of the list is .bm-item-list which is what I called out in the css to change the color.  Thanks for the tip